# How to add aria-label to carousel buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm using a carousel slider with jQuery and it automatically adds `owl-prev` and `owl-next` classes as shown below.

How can I add `role="prev"` and `role="next"` to the buttons just as with the classes so as to improve accessibility?

```
<div class="owl-nav">
 <button role="presentation" class="owl-prev"><i class="icofont-simple-left"></i></button>
 <button role="presentation" class="owl-next"><i class="icofont-simple-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: did you add the role="presentation" you should never change roles of HTML element. Button already has a role="button" by default. you can add and aria-label to the button saying next slide or previous slide

Comment: I'm improving accessibility on a code that I didn't work on. I'm not sure if it was changed or if it's there by default. Found this `navElement: 'button role="presentation"'` in `jquery.min.css`. I think it's the line responsible for the `role` and by removing it I get `<undefined class="owl-next"></undefined>` instead of the `button`.

Can you please elaborate on how to add the aria-label? Not that clear to me.

Comment: Try like this:  navElement: 'button aria-label="next slide" ' like said, button does not need a role so I removed the presentation role from it in my example

Comment: I agree it's a button, it doesn't need the role `button` again. And that works, thanks, but all the buttons have a label of 'next slide'. Can it be `next slide` and `previous slide`? instead of both reading next slide?

Comment: Should have of course, but not sure what is the rest of your code. Do you have to navElements for next and previous or is it just one. Probably need to create a condition or so

Comment: Just one, and I can provide any more info you need.